# String representation of an integer division in EL (not truncated)?

Tags: java, jsf, integer, el, division

I thought this would be an automatic:

```
<rich:tooltip value="Download (#{doc.size div 1024 + 1} KB)" />
```

I need to calculate the number of KB a file has for downloading (size is integral). In regular Java code the same calculation would **truncate** the fractional part and return that remaining integer. In JSF EL however, there's no truncating division, so the division return a float.

How is it done in EL anyway - that is **without** introducing a bean method that does the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`fn:split()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/fn/split.fn.html) to get rid of the fraction.

```html
<ui:param name="size" value="#{fn:split(doc.size / 1024, '.')[0]}" />
<rich:tooltip value="Download (#{size + 1} KB)" />
```

Be cautious: it's locale dependent. On some locales it's a comma `,`. I'd rather create/use an EL function for the job, something like as [OmniFaces `of:formatBytes()`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/functions/Converters) is doing.

```html
<rich:tooltip value="Download (#{of:formatBytes(doc.size)})" />
```

Comment: Ugh, such a problem... Isn't this basically a flaw of the EL that this isn't possible out of the box (easily)? Probably an idiv keyword?